# jQuery performance: grouped selectors vs individual

Tags: jquery, performance, dom, jquery-selectors

Take the following html:

```
<div class='div1'/>
<div class='div2'/>
<div class='div3'/>
```

Now let's say I want to hide these elements using jQuery `.hide()`. Performance wise is it better to group the 3 into a single selector.

```
$('.div1, .div2, .div3').hide();
```

Or to run 3 separate selectors.

```
$('.div1').hide();
$('.div2').hide();
$('.div3').hide();
```

For code readability I prefer the second method but I suspect the former method is faster?

Furthermore does the type of selection being made effect the outcome here. For example making a grouped selection using class tagname and id mixed?

```
$('.myClass, a, #myId').hide();
```

vs separate selectors.

```
$('.myClass').hide();
$('a').hide();
$('#myId').hide();
```

Comment: "Performance wise is it better ..." - did you [test that](http://jsperf.com/)?

Comment: @MosheKatz he's asking a question. He's not stating a fact. emphasis on the "Performance wise **is it** better ...".. he didnt say "Performance wise **it is** better ...".. sorry to nitpick :P

Comment: I didn't know how, until now..I'll run some tests

Comment: It looks like `$('div[class^=div]').hide()` would be the fastest selector for this group of objects.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy this selector performed worse that the other two http://jsperf.com/single-vs-grouped-jquery-selectors

Comment: @QF_Developer I think it depends on the browser from which you're testing. in FireFox 19 on Windows Vista Business 64 bit, it was faster by 19%.

Comment: @passionateCoder See further down: "...I suspect the former method is faster..."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*is it better to group the 3 into a single selector*?

The only difference between them is that one is more readable than other(*as you already prefer*),You can use anyone based on your choice as they do not have a big difference in [performance](http://jsperf.com/group) -

[image]

*does the type of selection being made effect the outcome here*?

No, this doesn't make any difference to the outcome -

- http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

Comment: "does the type of selection being made effect the outcome here?" - it does when used individually - `#idSelector` on its own will be queried using `getElementById` while the rest is handled by Sizzle. [core.js#L129](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/9fdbc8bf33418f7b3a3a88df9a04ffee53c8dc66/src/core.js#L129)

Comment: @FabrícioMatté  And that effect the outcome ?

Comment: I just ran the same test with broadly similar results (Testing in Chrome 27.0.1453.116 32-bit on Windows 8 64-bit). In my case grouping was 20% slower.

Comment: Eh the difference is a minimum performance gain, just felt like adding a small note. `=]`

Comment: @QF_Developer  Just re-run your test multiple times, you will surely see different results.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté that is true, you'd need to have some pretty intensive loops to notice any difference. Fortunately the most readable method is also the best in terms of performance.

Comment: @QF_Developer Yes, I made a [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/id-vs-class-selector-829892/3) to check and both are really fast. Anyway when performance is crucial, one'd use the native DOM APIs instead.

Answer (score 0):

### [Here's the benchmarks](http://jsfiddle.net/pb6jr/)

It looks like grouped is slightly faster.

```
Mixed Individual: 8ms
Mixed Grouped: 6ms
Individual: 15ms
Grouped: 9ms
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's your answer:

http://jsperf.com/single-vs-multiple-selectors

Googling "jsperf Jquery selector performance" yields many different test cases covering all kinds of performance runs.

Generally Jquery selectors have to be split into their individual components to be processed. As such this results in a slight cost increase when they are all in one selector.

Unless you encounter performance issues it's not really worth worrying about this. Focus on readability.